# Test of stationarity Vs. stl in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a weekly time series with approximately 2 years of data. I wanted to check whether my series is stationary or not. To check stationary, I used two test,Augmented Dickey-Fuller test,here is the code I used `adf.test(data, alternative = "stationary")` I got p value as 0.01 & a warning message is saying that p-value smaller than printed p-value. Secondly I used Priestley Subba Rao Test,here is the code `stationarity(data)` & I got p-value for T             : 0.1717033 . Both of the test are suggesting that my data is stationary. But when I used `plot(stl(data_ts,52))` where `data_ts<-ts(data,start = c(2014,1),frequency = 52)` to check it visually,I got following chart [image] & it is showing an increasing trend in my data.Which is suggesting a violation of stationarity. I'm completely confused with these contradicting outputs. Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your time series is probably stationary. The output charts are on different scales which makes the trends angle look sharper than it is (the bar on the right reflects how much the scale is increased in each chart) if you look at the top chart, it ranges between 0 to 0.15 whereas the trend chart has a scale ranging from 0.04 to 0.055. If you plot the trend on the same scale as the raw series it will probably look completely flat...